# having trouble understanding code, specifically the &

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am reading a tutorial regarding a Java pacman game.

Here is the code in question.

```
   if (pacmanx % blocksize == 0 && pacmany % blocksize == 0) {
        pos = // integer         
        ch = screendata[pos];

        if ((ch & 16) != 0) { // do not understand this.
            screendata[pos] = (short)(ch & 15);
            ...
        }
```

I am not really understanding the single &. I understand this operand checks both sides of an if statement, or is a bitwise operator. However, per the tests below, it doesn't seem to be either:

```
if I was to test (ch = 18):
(ch & 16) = 16
(ch & 8) = 0
(ch & 2) = 2
```

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`&` is the [bitwise operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) AND:

```
18 = 10010
16 = 10000
----------
16 = 10000


18 = 10010
 8 = 01000
----------
 0 = 00000
```

So the `if` will check if the fifth bit is 1 or 0.

Comment: ok, understood the bitwise operator. however, what is the if statement doing? I dont understand, what you mean by checking the fifth bit

Comment: @dgamma3 The information for the pacman game seems to be somehow endoded bitwise. The `if` checks if the fifth bit is set (is equal to 1). If so, the first four bits are used for the screendata... Can't really guess more based on this code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

The single `&` it's a [bitwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) `AND`. It's an and operation performed on individual bit of your number.

Consider a possible bit representation of your short:

```
10011011 &   : screendata[pos]
00010000 =   : 16
----------
10010000
```

Specifically this line:

```
if ((ch & 16) != 0) {
```

check if the 5-th bit (2^ (5 -1)) of your number is set to 1 (different from 0).

Answer (score 2):

That's not a Boolean and, which is always `&&`; instead it's a bitwise and. It's checking to see if the 5th bit from the right is set in `ch`.

```
ch = 18  //      ch = 0b00010100
ch & 16  //      16 = 0b00010000
         // ch & 16 = 0b00010000 != 0
ch & 8   //       8 = 0b00001000
         // ch &  8 = 0b00000000 == 0
ch & 2   //       2 = 0b00000010
         // ch &  2 = 0b00000010 != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Given `ch = 18`

```
(ch & 16) = 16
(ch & 8) = 0
(ch & 2) = 2
```

seems correct. What's 18 in binary ? `16 | 2` or `10010` in binary.

To be clear, `&` is a bitwise operator. However `&&` returns true if both operands are true.

Answer (score 0):

Single ampersand is a bitwise AND operator.

You might find it easier to "get" if the values were in hex.

Answer (score 0):

The bitwise and operator `&` performs an "and" on each bit of the two integers to determine the result.

So:

18 = 0001 0010
16 = 0001 0000
18&16 = 0001 0000

Answer (score 0):

& is bitwise operator AND. You can see detail in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html